# Rails complex nested forms with 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, actionview

This question concerns three models:

#### Sale

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_items
  has_many :items, through :sale_items
end
```

#### Item

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_items
  has_many :sales, :through => :sale_items
end
```

#### SaleItem

```
class SaleItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
  belongs_to :item
end
```

To explain, an `item` acts as a base template for a `sale_item`. The application has many `Item`s, but these are not necessarily a part of every `Sale`. So, `sale_item.name` actually points to `sale_item.item.name`, and `sale_item`'s `price` method looks like this:

```
def price
  super || item.price
end
```

A `sale_item` either gets its price from its `item`, or that price can be overridden for that specific `sale_item` by editing its `price` column in the database.

This is what I'm having difficulty with in my `sales/_form.html.erb` view: I essentially need a table of all `Item` objects that looks the table in this Tinkerbin: http://tinkerbin.com/46T7JAKs.

So, what that means is that if an unchecked checkbox gets checked and the form is submitted, a new `SaleItem` needs to be created with an `item_id` equal to that if the `Item` from the list, and with appropriate `price` and `quantity` fields (`quantity` is specific to `SaleItem` and does not exist for `Item` objects).

Additionally, if the `Sale` that is being edited already includes a specific `SaleItem`, that checkbox should already be checked when the form view is rendered (so unchecking a box for a row would delete the `SaleItem` object associated with that `Item` and this `Sale`).

I'm not sure how this could be done—maybe I'm doing it wrong from the beginning. I toyed with the idea of doing away with the `SaleItem` model altogether and just creating a `items_sales` table with the fields `sale_id`, `item_id`, `price`, and `quantity`, but I'm not sure that is the best pattern.

---

### Update

The previous solution I posted ended up with some flaws and failing tests. I finally figured it out, but will post the real solution shortly.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? getting the checkbox to call the controller? what to write in the controller?

Comment: I essentially need to end up with multiple forms for each individual possible `SaleItem`, and this is what I can't figure out how to do. I'm not sure how to build the view.

Comment: You want this to be an on click action? meaning each checkbox clicked calls the controller to update, or do u want there to be a save button on the bottom which submits all changes?

Comment: I was planning on doing this with a single submit button at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to have is a checkbox tag with an array which will hold on submission an array of all selected id's, so instead of the html checkbox use the checkbox helper:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'sale_item_ids[]', item.id -%>
```

On submission the params hash will hold the ids of the selected item's. What you need to do now is loop on each of these and do the appropriate creation of the relationship (sale_item). You must also loop on those that exist already for this sale and delete them if they are not in the array submited.

Upon creating the actual html page you can check if the id of the checkbox is already in the sale and check/uncheck it accordingly.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Although it's the least detailed answer, it's the one that pointed me in the right direction and helped me get it solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the author of [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), a gem that will make creating dynamically nested forms easier, I would like to point you to a sample project called [cocoon_simple_form_demo](http://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo), that contains all kinds of nested forms, including this type.

I have also written a [blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=561) describing all these.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What if you treat the join table more like a normal rails model.

```
class SaleItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :sale_items do |t|
  t.integer :sale_id
  t.integer :item_id
  t.float :price
  t.float :quantity

  t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

Then you can do things like

controller

```
@sale = Sale.new
@saleitem = @sale.SaleItem.build
```

You can add a item select for every line in the form. With some javascript you can update the price field from the item selected and change it if you want.

Even better than select, check out this [railscast on auto complete association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised) (if you don't have a pro account on railscast(get one!) go [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association)

For adding lines til the Sale form take a look at this [railscast on complex forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3)

Comment: That's exactly what my SaleItems table already looks like. If I use `@saleitem = @sale.SaleItem.build` in my controller, that only gives me a finite amount of `SaleObject` items. I need the number of forms rendered on the page to scale according to how many total `Item` objects there are.

Comment: Hello. lend 10 minutes to Ryan[railscast 74](http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2). This show how to do it, but not with jQuery. Make a partial with <% fields_for "sale[sale_item_attributes][]", sale_item do |sale_item_form| %> and the fields you need. Then make a javascript link to generate more fields_for as you need.